# 403 Forbidden Error while creating list item using angularjs

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

I am trying to create a list item using **angularjs Http service**, but am getting an error **403 Forbidden**. PFB the code:

```
    <script src="http://win-pmmmma92p9v:19522/sites/JobSeekers/Resources/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://win-pmmmma92p9v:19522/sites/JobSeekers/Resources/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script>

    var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myController",function($scope,$http)

    {

    $scope.addQuestion = function(){

    return $http({
    headers:{"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest":$("#_REQUESTDIGEST").val(),"content-type":"application/json:odata=verbose"},
    method:"POST",
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Questions')/items",
    data:{
    'Title' : $scope.Title,
    'Description':$scope.Description,
    'Tag':$scope.Tag

    }


    }).then(saveContact)
    .catch(function(message)
    {
    console.log("addQuestion() error:"+message);
    });
    function saveContact(data,status,headers,config)
    {
    alert("Item added successfully");
    return data.data.d;
    }
    }
    });

    </script>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
Title<br>
<input type="text" ng-module="Title" id="title"><br><br>
Description<br>

<textarea ng-module="Description" id="description"></textarea><br><br>

Tag<br>
<input type="text" ng-module="Tag" id="tag"><br><br>

<button ng-click="addQuestion()">Post Your Question</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have been trying it for two days, but still dint find any solution, can someone help?

Comment: could you try referencing the jquery and angularjs file from library instead of cdn links?

Comment: are you able to add list items manually ? 403 means that you dont have permission to add list items.

Comment: I have referenced files from my library itself @SharePointGoa

Comment: Yes I am able to add list items manually @Gautham Sheth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some typing mistake in your code in header section like ..

1. You have written Colon (:) instead of semicolon (;) in content type section.
2. There should be double underscore in `$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()` but you have written single underscore.

Plus you have to add `__metadata` section which is mission in your code.

**Refer/Use below function for `addQuestion`. It will work for you.**

```
 var addQuestion = function() {

        return $http({
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                method: "POST",
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Songs')/items",
                data: {
                    __metadata: {
                        "type": "SP.Data.SongsListItem"
                    },
                    'Title': $scope.Title,
                    'Description': $scope.Description,
                    'Tag': $scope.Tag
                }


            }).then(saveContact)
            .catch(function(message) {
                console.log("addQuestion() error:" + message);
            });

        function saveContact(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Item added successfully");
            return data.data.d;
        }
    }
```